# Elliptic point addition on Java Cards?

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, smartcard, javacard

For Java Card 3.0.5, are there any methods/workarounds to add two discrete points together? For example, for scalar multiplication the method I found is `ALG_EC_SVDP_DH_PLAIN_XY`. Is there something like this for discrete point addition? I'm aware of `ALG_EC_PACE_GM` which does `sG + H`. But that isn't really discrete point addition since I would need to know some `s` for which `sG` would result in the point I need.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to make a Schnorr signature implementation (since it doesn't exist for Java Card natively) and for that I would need EC point addition.

**OR ALTERNATIVELY**, if anyone has any links to existing opensource implementations of the Schnorr signature for Java Card, I'd love that also.

I am aware of JCMathLib, but its rather heavy.

Comment: If you can access the source code, you can since scalar multiplication includes the point addition...

Comment: Nxp has a proprietary lib for this on some jcop cards

Comment: Yeah but I don't have access to the source code...